# Using Babel with Mako templates in tornado Web Application

Tags: internationalization, tornado, mako, babeljs

I have a tornado application, which uses Mako for templating. Using Babel I was able to create translations (mo files) but When I am not able to render the translated string.

My html block (index.mako):

```
`<li> <a id="login"> ${_('Login')} / ${_('Signup')} </a></li>`
```

handler.py
    class HomeHandler(BaseHandler):

```
    def get(self):
        hometemplate = makoLookup.get_template("index.mako")
        response_str = hometemplate.render()
        self.write(response_str)
```

response_str returns 
    `<li> <a id="login"> Login / Signup </a></li>`

How do I implement internationalization in mako? All the document i searched explains extracting translations but could not find any document on using translations in mako templates.

I have tried using Tornado-Babel but could not find document on integrating with mako templates.

Answer (score 0):

Using TornadoBabelMixin. I pass the self._ to my template rendering function. Now my handler code looks like this.

```
class HomeHandler(TornadoBabelMixin, BaseHandler):
    def get_user_locale(self):
        return locale.get("en_US")

    def get(self):
        hometemplate = makoLookup.get_template("index.mako")
        response_str = hometemplate.render(_ = self._)
        self.write(response_str)
```